# Deleting empty objects from extra row of DataGrid in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I've got a DataGrid in a user control bound to an ObservableCollection of an object. I've got CanUserAddRows set to true, because that's the functionality I'd like. However, when I close that window, any extra rows added by the user that are blank get added to my ObservableCollection. Is there any way to remove those extra items from my ObservableCollection if they're blank in a way that's MVVM compliant?

Comment: Handle the closing of the window in the view model and remove any last item that has the default values only?

Comment: Are you using any specific MVVM framework?

Comment: I'm not using any MVVM framework - just the standard boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2):

The "MMVM way" of doing something like this is to use event triggers to call commands that are bound to your view from your ViewModel. To use event triggers, you'll need the interactivity extension for WPF. You can grab that from NuGet ..

```
Install-Package System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF
```

This provides the `EventTrigger` that will be used to call a command when an event occurs. Now you need to add this trigger to your window XAML and set the trigger action to call a command. For example, here I am settings up a command to be called on the `Closing` event of the window.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RemoveEmptyEntries}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see I'm calling a command in the trigger. This command is obtained via binding to a RemoveEmptyEntries property expected to be on the ViewModel. Now that the XAML is ready to call a command, you need to add this command to your ViewModel. This is done using a `RelayCommand`. These types of commands are found in most MVVM frameworks such as MVVM Light. But no worries if you're not using a framework, it's just some more boilerplate code. Here is a very simple implementation of a `RelayCommand` that can be used to get you going.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _commandAction;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action commandAction)
    {
        _commandAction = commandAction;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _commandAction.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Note the the `RelayCommand` takes an `Action` when created and calls that `Action` when the command is executed.

Lastly, add a new property of type `RelayCommand` to your ViewModel, such as ..

```
public class DataRowsViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand RemoveEmptyEntries => new RelayCommand(RemoveEmptyEntriesExecuted);

    private void RemoveEmptyEntriesExecuted()
    {
        //Remove empty rows here.
    }
}
```

Now your logic for removing the empty rows can be dropped into the `RemoveEmptyEntriesExecuted` method.

Comment: Thank you Jason - I appreciate this a lot! Can I ask - is this also achievable with an attached property and if so is there a benefit to using one over the other?

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Yes you could create a `OnClosingCommand` that is an attachable property which has the logic to handle closing events and call a bound command. Which is better is a personal preference IMO. If you're looking to go heavy MVVM, I would favor the interactions because they'll be familiar to anyone else with MVVM experience. It's also better for rapid dev; creating attachable properties gets cumbersome. But attachable properties have the advantage of not involving the extra assembly and learning new triggers. So I'd say it's whatever works best for you (and your team).

Comment: ^I just realized you may have meant an attachable property that does the actual empty row removal. That's possible too, some kind of `ClearEmptyRowsOnExit` type property could work for sure. This removes needing `RelayCommand` and the triggers. So that's not wrong IMO, but again if you're looking at going heavy MVVM, I would favor logic in the view models and relay commands. You'll want that in the long run.